# Retrieve the value of a field from another class Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

EDIT : I want to retrieve the value of a field that is in Odoo's res.partner class. How to recover this value through the function `get_importid_SmartBambi` ?

field in res_partner :

```
importid_SmartBambi = fields.Char(string="Import_id_SmartBambi", compute='get_importid_SmartBambi', copy=False)
```

function class res.partner :

```
@api.one
def get_importid_SmartBambi(self):
    id_partner = self.id
    id_smart = self.env["ir.model.data"].sudo().search([('res_id', '=', id_partner), ('module', '=', 'horanet_tpa_smartbambi')])
    self.importid_SmartBambi = id_smart.name
```

function in other class :

```
def create_compte_cantine(self):

    print "Inscription réussie"
    idUsager = self.env['res.partner'].get_importid_SmartBambi

    return idUsager
```

EDIT : 
[image]

I want to get this number using the function `get_importid_SmartBambi(self)` already done in the class res.partner preferably.

The function `create_compte_cantine(self)` is in other class
Thanks you !

Comment: I modified my ad.

Comment: Yes, I will edit a little more code

Comment: the field "importid_SmartBambi" don't exist in res.partner model

Comment: The id was recovering but there was no write in the res.partner template. It was enough to put store = True here : importid_SmartBambi = fields.Char(string="Import_id_SmartBambi", compute='get_importid_SmartBambi', copy=False, store=True)

Comment: I suggest to you to describe first what you want to achieve and  then the issues?

Comment: I have edit my problem.

Comment: UP Help please for my problem

Comment: Add description of other class.to access res.partner you need a record id or an information about a partner to search.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `create_compte_cantine`, there are a few things to fix.

First, you need to retrieve the record of the `res.partner` with the desired `importid_SmartBambi`. Currently, your code uses `self.env['res.partner']`, which gives you the model only, but not a specific record. To retrieve the record, use

```
the_partners = self.env['res.partner'].search(... some suitable domain...)
the_partner = the_partners[0] if len(the_partners) > 0 else None
```

Once you have the desired record,  you can access the value using the field name that you defined:

```
the_partner.importid_SmartBambi
```